# How to add Synchronization Filter to outlook folder with c#

Tags: c#, filter, outlook, synchronization, add-in

I want to add automatically Synchronization Filters to Outlook folders.
I'm using Outlook 2015, and .NET Framework 5.0

I know how to the outlook instance and go over folders, but I can't find how to access a folder's Sync Filter.

This is done from within an AddIn I'm writing:
    In the AddIn class:
    Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace;

```
From the startup method:
outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
outlook.Folder folder = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

But I'm not sure how to access most of "folder" properties.

Comment: Which properties are you having trouble accessing? You need to be a lot more specific than just "I want to add automatically Synchronization Filters to Outlook folders". You might also want to take a look at the MAPIFolder object and its various child using OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll start with OutlookSpy to continue researching this.

As for properties:

1. When you delete outlook .ost file all Sync filters are deleted with the file.

2. This means I have to go through any relevant folder and set the Sync Filter again.

3. We have a lot of emails incoming, which means, we delete it every now and then.

4. I only need to set (For many folders) a filter to sync only "1 week ago" and forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder synchronization properties are not programmatically accessible.